# In maximum likelihood estimation, why is it hard to directly optimize the likelihood function?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

***In Boyd's Chapter 7, it writes***

[image]

I am just wondering what is the reason we do not maximize the likelihood function directly and instead construts the log-likelihood function?

What is the fundamental reason that makes the product of densities harder to maximize? Is it because it is difficult to test convexity, generate gradient, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

In small-$n$ problems, optimizing the likelihood may be tractable, and is in practice sometimes done.  However optimizing a likelihood function that involves the product of *many* terms (for instance $n \sim 10^8$) is computationally difficult because you must take derivatives of extremely high powers of terms and cross terms.  It is much simpler to optimize a *sum* of these terms.

Comment: I would argue that if you're careful about how the calculations are organized, the difference in complexity for computing the derivative can be made negligible. After all, let's say you have a fast procedure for computing the gradient of $h(x) =\log f(x)$. Then taking the gradient of both sides, we have $\nabla h(x) = (f(x))^{-1} \nabla f(x)$, or $\nabla f(x) = f(x) \nabla h(x)$. So assuming the "gather"-like operation to compute $f(x)$ is itself feasible, yo